# Multiple instance of Docker service with different config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Does anyone know if it is possible to scale a docker service (with Compose or Swarm) to say, 3 instances, each with a slightly different config? For example, they need to form a cluster and their names are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to give us more details.

But if you only want an example...you can find one here https://github.com/akka/akka-sample-cluster-docker-compose-scala/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Ok, I see. So the general way is configuring the multiple instances individually in a compose file? I was reading about making Eureka highly available, and for example, 3 peers need to point to each other as their peers (1 -> 2,3 / 2 -> 1,3 / 3 -> 1,2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

For example, you can configure hostnames of docker swarm service using [templates](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates)

Another way is configuring each instance of service differently after instances went up. You can delay container's main process startup using custom docker image which extends base image and has `RUN sleep [some_time]` as the last directive before image `ENTRYPOINT` which runs the main process.  After containers are running, you can configure each container differently and kill sleep in each container.